# git patches won't apply

Tags: git, diff, patch

I have two repos and made a .patch file from one. Inside it the path looks like this:

a/views/filename
b/views/filename

I made the patch file by checking out the branch and running `git format-patch -number` for the commits I needed. The files look to have the diffs I need, and the relative paths look correct.

However, when I try to `git am --signoff` the patch in my other repo (which has a different absolute structure but same relative structure) from the same relative position, I get an error like:

error: views/filename: does not exist in index

Any help?? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add the first 10 lines of your patch ?